# how can I create .csv file for watson Natural Language Classifier

Tags: ibm-watson

My .csv format is like this

```
Good evening,Greeting
good morning,Greeting
good afternoon,Greeting
hi everybody,Greeting
1,quantity
2,quantity
3,quantity
4,quantity
5,quantity

I would like you to give me *,OrderPlacement
I need *,OrderPlacement
I needed *,OrderPlacement
Please send *,OrderPlacement
```

Now input text is I need 3 pens then  NLC set higher confidence to quantity.  So how can I resolve this error?

Comment: I think you're using it in the wrong way. NLC is not a parser. It will use phrases to calculate the probability of some statement to belong to some category. Your quantities for example won't work.

Answer (score 2):

There are a number of issues.

The purpose of NLC is to train off questions in a natural language format. Using those questions, it is able to determine the intent of a question it is never seen before.

Because of this, your training data has to be proper English. These lines will not work:

```
1,quantity
2,quantity
3,quantity
4,quantity
5,quantity
```

Instead it should be in a way that someone may ask, and not all the same pattern. For example:

```
I would like to buy 1 item,quantity
Can I get 2 items?, quantity
Please add three items to my basket, quantity
I want to purchase four boxes of your product, quantity
Please send me five boxes, quantity
```

Even then I would recommend not to manufacture questions. As you are training it on how you speak, and not your end user.

Also as @Leo mentioned, NLC is not a parser. So these lines will not work:

```
I would like you to give me *,OrderPlacement
I need *,OrderPlacement
I needed *,OrderPlacement
Please send *,OrderPlacement
```

Because they are incomplete sentences. You have lost the intent of the original question.

Lastly NLC requires a minimum of 5 questions per intent to correctly train.

You can read more details on how it works in the [service API document](https://www.ibm.com/smarterplanet/us/en/ibmwatson/developercloud/doc/nl-classifier/data_format.shtml).

Comment: suppose user Input is I need 3 pen  so we want class should be OderPlacement.
and If user jsut input number like 3  so we want class should be quantity.